# What is the difference between int* p and int (*p)[] in the context of arrays.?

Tags: c, pointers

Using DevCpp with TDM GCC 4.9.2 on Windows 8. But I don't think the platform matters for this question.

I know that we can use a pointer to point to a single data or an array of data.
I have learned about pointer to arrays but never used it. What advantage does one have over the other?

Sample Code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x[2]={10,20};
    int *p1= NULL; //simple pointer
    int (*p2)[] = NULL; //pointer to an array, specifically

    p1 = x;
    p2 = &x; //removing the & gives me a warning of "assignment from incompatible pointer types".

    printf("x[1] = %d\n", x[1]);

    *(p1+1) = 7;

    printf("x[1] = %d\n", x[1]);

    (*p2)[1] = 55;

    printf("x[1] = %d", x[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Does p1 or p2 have an advantage over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are completely different.

`int *p;` - is the pointer to the int

`int (*p)[1];` is a pointer to the array (in this case one element only)

In your trivial example the pointer arithmetic will be the same and generated code will be the same. But they still have different types and you may get warnings when compiled.

The "advantages" you will see when your example will be less trivial:

`int (*p)[100];`

`p++;` the pointer will point to the next 100 elements int array.

Comment: I did not realize that pointer arithmetic thing you mentioned. Nice point.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer to an array means a pointer which accepts address of an array.
let's say array is int arr[5],in which size of int is 4 byte.
p is a pointer to an array that accept the address of an int array.

```
int arr[5];
int (*p)[5];
p=&arr;//address of an array block
```

let's say the base address is 1000 .So after increment in p it will lead us to  1020 address,because the size of the array block is 20 bytes.
     p points to 1000 address

```
p++;
//Now p points to 1020 not 1004.
```

Whereas in case of int *q, q will point to 1004 as usual.

Comment: Understood. You elaborated nicely what @P__J__ said.